# 3D interactive terrain visualization with GRASS 7

Tags: ubuntu, grass-7.0

GRASS 6 had an interesting and interactive terrain visualization tool which was based on Tcl/Tk and called NViz. After my Ubuntu 15.10 updated itself for GRASS 7.0, the NViz interactive tool is missing.

What can I do to install NViz / interactively visualize terrains?

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 / 64 bit / GRASS 7.0.

Comment: Indian, the @gene's answer is pretty good a sufficient I think, consider accepting the answer, so this is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Nviz was replaced by [WxNviz](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxNviz) (in Python)

[image]

[image]