# NVIZ not installed/working?

Tags: ubuntu, grass-7.0

I am running GRASS GIS 7.0.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

After completing a tutorial on extruding vector data, I tried running the nviz command to see the result in a 3D-view.

[image]

This is in norwegian, but it tells me that the folder/file nviz does not exist. What am I missing here?

Comment: Nviz was replaced by WxNviz (in Python), look at  [3D interactive terrain visualization with GRASS 7](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/183911/2581)